# C++ treating this as a const when it isn't

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constants, this

I'm trying to compile some C++ code with Visual Studio 2010 but am getting the following error:

> error C2664: 'molder::Mold::set_piece_maker' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'piece_maker::Piece_Maker *const ' to 'piecemaker::Piece_Maker *'

That error is referring to two mirror functions that manage a mutual reference between two classes:

```
void Piece_Maker::set_mold(molder::Mold* value, void* origin) {
    if (this->mold == value)
        return;

    this->mold = value;
    this->mold->set_piece_maker(this, this); // This is the line with the error
}
```

and:

```
void Mold::set_piece_maker(piecemaker::Piece_Maker* value, void* origin) {
    if (this->piece_maker == value)
        return;

    this->piece_maker = value;
    this->piece_maker->set_mold(this, this);
}
```

- I'm not using const with either of these classes anywhere.
- The error only happens with the mold->set_piece_maker() line, while the mirrored piece_maker->set_mold() line compiles just fine.
- The compiler is claiming "this" is const but isn't flagging my modification of its mold property, and is not flagging my passing "this" as the origin parameter.
- When I actually make set_mold() const, then the compiler raises errors for trying to modify mold in that function and trying to pass "this" as origin.

What could be happening for the compiler to raise that error?

Comment: The title and body of the question was about understanding a general compiler error message.  When searching for error messages involving invalid const conversions, every case involved explicit use of const in the code.  My main confusion was that the compiler showed an argument as const when my code did not contain any.  Without the const part I would have immediately noticed the spelling difference.

Is there another question on stack overflow that discusses this nature of this error message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not the `const`, which is a top-level `const` and ignored anyway.  Take a look at the two types lined up vertically:

```
piece_maker::Piece_Maker *const
piecemaker::Piece_Maker *
```

Comment: And of course, `piece_maker::Piece_Maker` is a different type than `piecemaker::Piece_Maker`.  He's almost certainly got a spelling error somewhere.

Comment: I got so focused on the const I didn't see that I had misspelled one of the namespaces.  The odd thing is the compiler wasn't throwing any errors about that.

Comment: @silentorb: Having two differently named namespaces with similar class names inside is not itself an error. But in fact, your compiler *did* throw an error, it was just misleading for your actual problem.